# How do I avoid duplicates when using a reference field?

Tags: views, 8

I have a content type with an entity reference field. If I have more then one entity in this field, and display the field in a view, it displays  duplicates.

Anyone figured out how to remove these duplicates in Drupal 8?

Comment: In your edit view, Under advanced, try enabling aggreation.

Comment: Yeah i did, and was a no go. I turned on aggregation, and also tried with and without Distinct. I may be missing something, but it doesn't function the say way as in 7 as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I removed the duplicates using hook_views_pre_render().

```
function hook_views_pre_render(\Drupal\views\ViewExecutable $view) { 
  if ($view->id() == 'my_view_id') {
    $filtered_nids = array();

    foreach ($view->result as $key => $row) {
      if (in_array($row->nid, $filtered_nids)) {
        unset($view->result[$key]); // remove the duplicate
      } else {
        $filtered_nids[] = $row->nid;
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

Probably not the best solution, but it works for my case.

Comment: Nice one! Needed an extra condition  `&& $view->current_display === 'block_2'` to only target a specific display. See an example: [claro_views_pre_render](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21themes%21claro%21claro.theme/function/claro_views_pre_render/9).